# Libgdx reducing calls and optimize the game

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Am trying to reduce number of calls being made everytime a Screen is called on my game in a bid to make my game faster and I noticed I do alot the same calculation on every screen..how can i avoid this?

I do this in practically every screen

```
public class ****Screen implements Screen {
    @Override
    public void show() {

    float screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    float gameWidth = 360;
    float gameHeight = screenHeight / (screenWidth / gameWidth);
    midPointY = (int) (gameHeight / 2);
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(true, gameWidth, gameHeight);
    viewport = new FitViewport(gameWidth, gameHeight, cam);
    viewport.apply();
    stage = new Stage(viewport);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

yet I have a GameClass..How can I implement the above in my gameclass(below) and only have to call it once?...

```
public class Start extends Game {
     @Override
    public void create() {
    float screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    float gameWidth = 360;
    float gameHeight = screenHeight / (screenWidth / gameWidth);

    assets = new AssetLoader();
    assetManager = new AssetManager();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(true, gameWidth, gameHeight);

    //initialize screens here
    mainMenu = new MenuScreen(this);
    loadingScreen = new LoadingScreen(this);
    gameScreen = new GameScreen(this);

    .......

    //call assets
    AssetLoader.load();

    //start mainmenu...
    this.setScreen(mainMenu);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i have to tell you actualy this wont speed up your game.
If you change screen every 20 seconds then that means game does calculations 1 frame per 1200 frames. 
However i am same like you and really looking for most optimize ways while doing game.

I found a solution for this case.
You can pass objects that you use in all screens, from game class to screen class.

Screen class

```
public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen {

    public MainMenuScreen(OrthographicCamera camera) {
        this.camera=camera;
    }

//...Rest of class omitted for succinctness.
}
```

Game class

```
public class Starts extends Game {

 OrthographicCamera camera;
    public void create() {
        camera=new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
        this.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(camera));// change screen and pass camera to new screen.
    }

}
```

Or you can even pass the whole game class like this.

```
public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen {

final Starts game;
public MainMenuScreen(final Starts game) {
    this.game = game;

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    game.camera.update();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(game.camera.combined);

    game.batch.begin();
    game.font.draw(...);
    game.font.draw(...);
    game.batch.end();

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        game.setScreen(new AnotherScreen(game));
        dispose();
    }
}

}
```

just need to call like this in game class. So you can use stage batches fonts etc. of game in all screens.

```
this.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this));
```

Comment: Thanks..Turns out I was calling the entire Game class all this time and never even thought to implement the screenwidth and screenheight there

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean you want to shorten the little hiccup you get when switching screens. (Your game's frame rate is not affected by this.)

Easy way: move that code from `show` to the constructor of each screen class.

However, it is wasteful to be creating a new Stage for each Screen without passing it a SpriteBatch, because you are essentially instantiating three separate SpriteBatches, which are heavy objects (they have a big array for the mesh data, a big mesh on the GPU, and have to compile a shader).

You can instantiate shared objects in your Game class and pass them into the constructors of your Screens like this:

```
public class Start extends Game {
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

     @Override
    public void create() {
        //...

        //initialize screens here

        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(); //must be disposed in dispose()

        mainMenu = new MenuScreen(this, spriteBatch);
        loadingScreen = new LoadingScreen(this, spriteBatch);
        gameScreen = new GameScreen(this, spriteBatch);

        //...
    }
}
```

Update your Screens' constructors accordingly and pass the sprite batch into the stage constructors. Viewports and cameras are lightweight, so I wouldn't bother with moving those up to the Game class unless it helps make your code more maintainable.

By the way, you're kind of abusing FitViewport by pre-calculating the aspect ratio. The point of Viewports is that you don't need to calculate anything when setting up. Use `new ExtendViewport(360, 1, cam)` to get the same thing you're doing without the calculations. And make sure you're updating it in `resize()`.

Comment: Setting my gameHeight to 1 did not help in fact, the entire game shifted to a height of 1...Am I missing something?

Comment: ExtendViewport, not FitViewport. Also make sure to update it in resize.

Comment: Sorry about that..works great now..Also do I replace all instances of gameHeight with 1 now in my app? For example under labels, images, button.setPosition() .e.t.c

Comment: No, you can call `gameHeight = camera.getViewportHeight();` right after the viewport update in `resize()`.